# What does it mean to "construct a sequence"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am doing some Real Analysis homework, and one of the questions asks me to construct a sequence that obeys certain conditions-it is increasing etc. What does this mean exactly? What should my answer look like?

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingSequence.html). Do you know what a sequence is?

Comment: With constructing a sequence with certain properties they simply mean you have to make one up that satisfy given conditions, possibly using steps provided in your book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special mathematical meaning of the word "construct" in this context.  It just means your answer will be a sequence.  "Give" or "find" a sequence are other ways of phrasing it.

---

Very simple example:

**Construct a sequence whose terms are strictly increasing.**

Answer:  Let $a_n = n$ for all $n \ge 0$.  Then $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is a sequence whose terms are strictly increasing, because $a_{n+1} = n+1 > n = a_n$ for all $n \ge 0$.

---

Note that the notation you're using in your course may vary slightly.

Comment: Thank you. Silly question, good answer.

Comment: Your question is not silly. "Construct"  means build or assemble, but  also "to form an idea or theory, by bringing together various conceptual elements." (Oxford Online Dictionary) In mathematical jargon, "construct a sequence"  means "think of and describe a sequence so the rest of us can understand." The rub is that it's not clear just what descriptions are understandable. Those who do not accept the countable axiom of choice will not accept the construction of a sequence that others  have no quarrel with.  So the meaning of "construct" in English is clear in mathematical jargon it is not.